# Terminal doesn't launch from Dock or shortkeys

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

I cannot launch terminal from the Dock, favourites or by Ctrl+Alt+T. However, I can click the right mouse button on the desktop and choose Terminal and then it opens. I work on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome shell version 3.28.3. I played a bit with different python versions and **I think** it stopped working correctly then. What might be wrong?

Comment: Since you played with python, the solution in the post I marked as duplicate probably may help.

Comment: yes, it does. Thank you!